grpc client\server on the same ASP.NET Core service
I have two services, A and B, that communicate using gRPC. In 99% of cases, Service A acts as the client and calls Service B, which serves as the gRPC server. However, there are occasional scenarios where Service B needs to send a small message back to Service A.
The question is, it’s often considered a good practice to implement both a gRPC client and a gRPC server within the same service?
This way, Service B can also send messages to Service A when necessary.
Additional information about my project: Service A is a .NET Core backend that serves an Angular application.
It includes:

The Angular frontend, served by the backend.
An ASP.NET Core Web API backend with API controllers for communication with Angular
gRPC client call Service B.
The simplified schema is the following:


Goal: when an event occurs in Service B, it needs to notify Service A. Upon receiving this notification, Service A should use SignalR or a WebSocket to trigger a specific UI behavior in the Angular application, similar to a push notification.
Concern
I'm uncertain about the practice of having both a gRPC client and a gRPC server within the same service. Is this a sound approach, or could it lead to potential issues?
Consider also that in production I need to deploy as 2 separate container with the horizontal scaling feature.
I've implemented in both grpc server and client in both A and B. It works but I'm thinking for a different solution. Could be calling from B directly the API controller exposed by A?

A process can be a gRPC client and server at the same time, there is nothing wrong with it if that's your concern.

Consider

Bidirectional streaming RPCs where both sides send a sequence of messages using a read-write stream. The two streams operate independently, so clients and servers can read and write in whatever order they like: for example, the server could wait to receive all the client messages before writing its responses, or it could alternately read a message then write a message, or some other combination of reads and writes. The order of messages in each stream is preserved.

which is one of the use cases for gRPC as per the documentation, and which is not unusual.
Another approach which could work for your architecture is a message bus. But if you already bought into gRPC, then why not also use it for this purpose? So yes, certainly a viable solution.
